# Test value with IF and AND independently

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to test a cell against two conditions at 3 different times. This is for working tickets that have a number of minutes assigned for 3 different priorities.

```
Priority    Completed in (min)  SLA Test
1           15                  Pass
2           20                  Pass
3           70                  Fail
```

Priority 1 = 15, 2 = 30, 3 = 60

If the priority in C1 is equal to 1,2 or 3 and matches the number of minutes on the top right-hand side, return "pass" or "fail". I'm not sure how to run the tests "if" independently from one another

```
=IF(AND(C7=1,I7<=15) , "Pass", "Fail", IF(AND(c7=2,i7<=60) , "Pass", "Fail")
```

Pass or Fail after testing the 3 different priorities

Comment: Is I17 the time in he upper right side?  is it always I17 for the location of time?

Comment: based on what you have described, do an if function and AND function like you have started with.  Instead of the AND, perform a VLOOKUP or similar on your time in C1 on your table and return the completed in amount.  use = to compare this formula to your time in the upper right.  Place "pass" as your true result and "fail" as your false result.

Comment: Thanks Ed. Not sure is working. The idea is to test the number under "priority" if this number is 1 it means the time limit is 15 minutes, then I need to compare the "completed in" value against this. I'm not sure how VLOOKUP will do this. My issue is that I can't find a way to run the test independently of one another. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the table is located at `C6:D9`

Try any of these formulas:

1. Nested `IFs`

   `=
   IF( C7 = 1, IF( D7 <= 15, "Pass", "Fail"),
   IF( C7 = 2, IF( D7 <= 30, "Pass", "Fail"),
   IF( C7 = 3, IF( D7 <= 60, "Pass", "Fail") ) ) )`
2. Combining `CHOOSE` & `IF`:

   `= CHOOSE( C7,
   IF( D7 <= 15, "Pass", "Fail"),
   IF( D7 <= 30, "Pass", "Fail"),
   IF( D7 <= 60, "Pass", "Fail") )`

[image]

Comment: The use of `CHOOSE()` is nice, however you have overcomplicated it a little :)